# *** glibc detected *** /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000000000526d7f0 ***

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Would like to check if rviz is incompatible with groovy now? I am currently using ubuntu 12.04 and groovy.

i am managed to run the original rviz with minimal settings. however, for example, when i try to add in the laser scan data from the hokuyo node. it clashes and show the following errors. can anyone help me please? Thank you.

The error message shows

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/nav.rviz
[ INFO] [1393839197.213827908]: rviz version 1.9.34
[ INFO] [1393839197.213970839]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1393839197.626062602]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

or

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find rbx1_nav`/nav_test.rviz
[ INFO] [1393839262.349156655]: rviz version 1.9.34
[ INFO] [1393839262.349220165]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1393839262.758079698]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
*** glibc detected *** /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x000000000526d7f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f88b7addb96]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/RenderSystem_GL.so(_ZN4Ogre21GLHardwarePixelBuffer10freeBufferEv+0x1b)[0x7f887a0de39b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/RenderSystem_GL.so(_ZN4Ogre21GLHardwarePixelBuffer14blitFromMemoryERKNS_8PixelBoxERKNS_3BoxE+0x259)[0x7f887a0de939]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.7.4/RenderSystem_GL.so(_ZN4Ogre15GLTextureBuffer14blitFromMemoryERKNS_8PixelBoxERKNS_3BoxE+0x34)[0x7f887a0dfd64]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.7.4(_ZN4Ogre7Texture11_loadImagesERKSt6vectorIPKNS_5ImageENS_12STLAllocatorIS4_NS_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE+0x81e)[0x7f88b4f1bf9e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.7.4(_ZN4Ogre7Texture9loadImageERKNS_5ImageE+0x101)[0x7f88b4f1b541]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.7.4(_ZN4Ogre7Texture11loadRawDataERNS_9SharedPtrINS_10DataStreamEEEttNS_11PixelFormatE+0x79)[0x7f88b4f1a009]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOgreMain.so.1.7.4(_ZN4Ogre14TextureManager11loadRawDataERKSsS2_RNS_9SharedPtrINS_10DataStreamEEEttNS_11PixelFormatENS_11TextureTypeEifb+0x31c)[0x7f88b4f1e37c]
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/libdefault_plugin.so(_ZN4rviz10MapDisplay6updateEff+0x8e2)[0x7f8867c4b362]
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/librviz.so(_ZN4rviz12DisplayGroup6updateEff+0x81)[0x7f88b90d40b1]
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/librviz.so(_ZN4rviz20VisualizationManager8onUpdateEv+0x109)[0x7f88b917bd99]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectPKS_iPPv+0x2b1)[0x7f88b4146281]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x99)[0x7f88b414b179]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0xb4)[0x7f88b8500894]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x113)[0x7f88b8505713]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8c)[0x7f88b4131e9c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1ac1f2)[0x7f88b41631f2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1a9c0d)[0x7f88b4160c0d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x133)[0x7f88b2eb6d13]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x48060)[0x7f88b2eb7060]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x34)[0x7f88b2eb7124]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x6f)[0x7f88b41613bf]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4(+0x273d9e)[0x7f88b85a8d9e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x32)[0x7f88b4130c82]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0xf7)[0x7f88b4130ed7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0x87)[0x7f88b4135f67]
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz(main+0x4c)[0x400b0c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f88b7a8076d]
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz[0x400ba1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 2368934                            /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:07 2368934                            /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 2368934                            /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz
0143c000-0577e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
402da000-40378000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
40963000-40965000 r-xs 00000000 08:07 266350                             /tmp/glAhESiD (deleted)
41038000-410d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
41985000-41a23000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8840000000-7f8840021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8840021000-7f8844000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8846bed000-7f8846fff000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 3145730                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f8846fff000-7f88473ff000 rw-s 1cb760000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f88473ff000-7f88477ff000 rw-s 1da5c0000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f88477ff000-7f8847bff000 rw-s 1ce432000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f8847df6000-7f8847dff000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1311                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
7f8847dff000-7f8847ffe000 ---p 00009000 08:07 1311                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
7f8847ffe000-7f8847fff000 r--p 00008000 08:07 1311                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
7f8847fff000-7f8848000000 rw-p 00009000 08:07 1311                       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
7f8848000000-7f8848021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8848021000-7f884c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f884c000000-7f884c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f884c021000-7f8850000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8850000000-7f8850021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8850021000-7f8854000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8854000000-7f8854021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8854021000-7f8858000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8858000000-7f8858021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8858021000-7f885c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f885c000000-7f885c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f885c021000-7f8860000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8860000000-7f8860021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8860021000-7f8864000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f88641e4000-7f8864244000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 3178499                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7f8864244000-7f8864344000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8864344000-7f8864744000 rw-s 1cb5e0000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f8864744000-7f8864944000 rw-s 1ce46e000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f8864964000-7f8864e45000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8864e45000-7f8864e46000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8864e46000-7f8865646000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:21792]
7f8865646000-7f8865647000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8865647000-7f8865e47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:21786]
7f8865e47000-7f8866047000 rw-s 1d68a2000 00:05 15963                     /dev/nvidia0
7f8866047000-7f8866198000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3547283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
7f8866198000-7f8866398000 ---p 00151000 08:07 3547283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
7f8866398000-7f88663a0000 r--p 00151000 08:07 3547283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
7f88663a0000-7f88663a2000 rw-p 00159000 08:07 3547283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
7f88663a2000-7f88663a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135196/***-glibc-detected-***-/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz:-free():-invalid-next-size-(normal):-0x000000000526d7f0-***/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Current rviz for groovy from .debs crashing when displaying data like pointclouds or laser scans is a known issue, see also [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/126766/ros-rviz-groovy-segfault-and-assertion-fail/), [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/131231/how-to-show-scan-and-map-topic-simultaneously-in-rviz/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/133766/error-while-compiling-rviz/)

There are two ways around this:

- Compiling rviz yourself

or

- Using the fuerte or hydro versions
  (the latter is recommended)

You´ll find info about those two in the links I posted.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-03-03**:
I have read the 1st link but not the latter two. Thanks alot :)